# PHP. Assigning values to an array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

OK, simple question. New to PHP. How do I accomplish something similar to the following in PHP? This is no specific language intentionally.

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
k = 50;
While i <= 5
  While j <= 10
    myarray(i,j) = k
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
      k = k + 2
  next
next
```

---

I have found much info regarding arrays and loops in PHP and none seem to accomplish this simple task. Please don't be snarky... just give me a hand here.

Comment: You probably mean to start each inner `while j<=10` with `j=0`. In that case you will need to put the assignment after `while i<=5`. In PHP you can combine both statements in a `for ($j=0; $j<=10; $j++)` expression.

Comment: I am new here and do not understand. I have researched this and not found an answer, but I was downvoted because my question exhibited no research effort!  Maybe I am being a bit hard headed, but the reason that I am here is because my research did not find me a solution! Just looking for simple assistance by someone who knows PHP. If the question is not up to the standards of this site, someone please give me some guidance.

Comment: Please write out the script youre trying to write. Also please include your effort.

Comment: Mr. Massmann, thank you for your response.  One of my biggest issues is the assignment of a value to the array. It seems as though PHP does not allow me to reference and assign values to an array as I am used to in other languages. Am I correct in this or (as I remarked earlier) just being hard headed and it is very much the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start each inner while `j<=10`.
Note that you didn't set $j to 0.
So correct the code is follows:

```
$i = 0;
$k = 50;
While( $i <= 5 ) {
  $j = 0;
  While( $j <= 10) {
    $myarray[$i][$j] = $k;
    $j++;
    $k = $k + 2;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. One thing to point out, the line $myarray($i,$j)=$k resulted in an error. The error went away when I changed to $myarray[$i][$j]=$k.

Answer (score -1):

Your pseudo code leaves some ambiguities, but maybe you mean to do the following:

```
$k=50;
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
  for ($j=0; $j<=10; $j++, $k+=2)
    $myarray[$i][$j]=$k;
```

This is a nested for-loop. The actual assignment to `$myarray` will happen `6*11=66` times in total and `$k` will have values from 50 to 115.

In PHP arrays don't need to be declared. You can simply assign a value to an arbitrary index of a given variable.

Here is a little [demo](https://rextester.com/RTDYR53574).